# What do sehlats eat?

Tags: star-trek

Are [sehlats](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sehlat) like the Vulcans and are vegetarians? That wouldn't make much sense since they have six inch fangs

**What is their diet?**

Comment: They eat Vulcan children who don't feed them at the right time.

Comment: @Valorum: So if the children show up on time, the Sehlat won't eat them?

Comment: @jwodder - That seems to be precisely the point

Comment: Same as grizzly bears: anything they want.

Answer (score 2):

According to the licenced RPG module *[Planets of the UFP](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Planets_of_the_UFP)*, sehlats are *omnivorous* creatures and that their fangs, while fearsome, are largely used to dig up small burrowing animals.

> The sehlat is a popular Vulcan pet, especially with children. Caring
> for a pet is regarded as a task which teaches children responsibility
> and compassion, so most Vulcan parents encourage their children to own
> pets. The sehlat is a furry quadruped with tan or brown fur, a short
> muzzle, and blunt claws designed for climbing; it fills the same
> ecological niche on Vulcan as bears do on Earth (though it sometimes
> runs in packs like wolves). Many humans refer to the sehlat as the
> "Vulcan teddy bear;" visitors are often surprised to discover that the
> sehlat is a 70- 350 kg animal with 15-cm fangs. In the wild the sehlat
> lives in temperate forests and mountains (some varieties can also
> thrive in desert mountains). It is an omnivore which uses its long
> fangs to help it dig up roots, grubs, and burrowing animals.

[*The Star Trek Book*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/27209477-the-star-trek-book) makes mention that they will stalk humanoid prey, so evidently they're happy to catch and kill (and then eat) pretty much anything smaller than they are.

> The sehlat is a fierce beast with long fangs, yet Vulcan children look upon them with the same affection Earth children feel for teddy bears (though they are always careful not to be late with dinner). Sehlats can be domesticated, but live naturally in the harsh desert of Vulcan’s Forge. **Wild sehlats will stalk humanoid prey who enter their territory.**